# db4o query optimisation for a scheduling application

Tags: java, db4o

I'm just getting started with db4o in a scheduling application and I'm looking for an efficient way to retrieve rooms which are not booked between certain dates.

So, I have a collection of Room objects each of which has a collection of Booking objects (which can be empty). A Booking has a start date and and end date. I want to say 'get all the rooms that have no Bookings between DateA and DateB'.

I'm sure I could do this using a Native Query but since there's a date range involved (my understanding is date ranges aren't optimzed for NQ) and I need to do this query very frequently (many times per second for potentially more 10,000 rooms - the majority of which have no Bookings) I'm looking for more efficient alternatives.

Is there a way to phrase this using SODA? 
Or a better way to arrange my data model to get round this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using SODA Query

```
Date fromDate = null ; // assign reservation start dat
Date toDate = null ; // assign reservation upto
Query query = db.query();
query.constrain(Booking.class);
query.descend ("fromDate").constrain ( fromDate ).greater().equal ().
      and (query.descend ("toDate").constrain (toDate).smaller().equal());
ObjectSet<Booking> objectSet = query.execute();
```

Query for **all of the rooms which do not have a booking between fromDate and toDate**

```
 Query query = db.query();
query.constrain(Room.class);
query.descend ("bookingStartDate").constrain ( fromDate ).greater().equal ().and
(query.descend ("bookingEndDate").constrain (toDate).smaller().equal()).not();
ObjectSet<Room> objectSet = query.execute();
```

**See Also :** [Building SODA Queries](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.13-flare/java/Content/object_lifecycle/querying/soda_query/building_soda_queries.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but doesn't that just give me all the bookings within the date range? I'm looking for all of the rooms which don't have bookings within the date range.

Comment: Sorry, I think my reply was unclear: it looks to me like your example is intended to return all of the Bookings between fromDate and toDate. But that's not what I need: what I need is 'all of the rooms which do not have a booking between fromDate and toDate'

Comment: @DB check edit. `not` should work fine or do smaller than startDate and grater than endDate.

Comment: That's more along the lines I need but...a room can have multiple bookings (a Room has a List of Bookings - which may be null). However that's maybe enough for me to play around further with...

Comment: So? that query returns all the room which are not booked b/w the dates. that is the one you'd asked.

Comment: From some quick testing, I don't think it catches the cases where a room has a booking that overlaps the required range (the booking starts or ends (but not both) within the range). Or possibly my implementation to account for the the list of bookings is not quite right. I'll need to play around with it a bit and see what I can do with it.